# Does the E-Value always define the filament length extrusion in millimeters and/or does it directly give a stepper rotation?

Tags: marlin, g-code, extrusion, stepper, e-value

I understood on a fundamental level that E-value (in G-Code) was the length of filament pushed in millimetres. i.e. E=10 is 10 mm filament to push (with a firmware like Marlin translating this value to stepper motor RPM values).

Is that a correct statement?

Or does it sometimes indicate directly the RPM of steppers depending on a different firmware?

What happens to the E-value interpretation when working with a pellet extruder (such as a WASP3MT 3D printer) which uses spherical pellets and a screw extruder instead of filaments and stepper motors pushing said filament?